# Separate multiple columns of nested data and clean them at the same time using base R and Tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyr

Question: Is there a way for me to separate multiple nested columns and clean them all at the same time using base R and tidyverse? I've checked the other nested responses here, but nothing seems to fit.

My dataframe has nested data that follows the following format.

v1 is type = double, v2 is type = character

```
my_df
    v1      v2
1   1234    {"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61}
2   1235    {"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24}
3   1236    {"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10}
```

I am able to separate (up to 10) using tidyr::separate as:

```
my_df <- tidyr::separate(my_df, col=v2, into=c("v2_01", "v2_02"), sep = ",")
```

In the actual data, v2 is of varying length, meaning amount the nested data is different for each row. This is not an issue as I really only need the first 10 values of v2 stored in the column, after I separate, the rest is truncated, along with the ending } character. So far so good.

This produces:

```
    v1      v2_01               v2_02
1   1234    {"484391115444":192 "484391115442":61
2   1235    {"484391115432":52  "484391115443":24
3   1236    {"484391115302":11  "484391115161":10
```

Now I need to clean it (remove the { and " characters) and separate again on the colon.
I can do this as individual commands:

```
my_df$v2_01 <- gsub("\\{","", as.character(my_df$v2_01))
my_df$v2_01 <- gsub('"',"", as.character(my_df$v2_01))
```

#separating on the ":" character

```
my_df <- tidyr::separate(my_df, col=v2_01, into=c("v2_01", "v2_01_Num" ,sep = ":"))
```

This produces:

```
    v1      v2_01           v2_01_Num   v2_02           v2_02_Num   :
1   1234    484391115444    92          484391115442    61          :
2   1235    484391115432    52          484391115443    24          :
3   1236    484391115302    11          484391115161    10          :
```

So far, meh, I do get the ":" column now. This is functional at best.

My question is the following:
Is there a way for me to separate multiple columns and clean them all at the same time? I'm also getting the ":" column now too as output. I'm a little unfamiliar with looping in R, but going through and separating 10 variables out column by column manually seems horribly tedious and inefficient. The above code does work, but I have a other dataframes
where the columns with nested data are in the dozens.

maybe tidyverse's separate_rows?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you really set on having columns wide, instead of long? I understand you have key-value pairs in v2, would it not be more tidy to use a long table to separate them? Something along these lines: 

`
library(tidyverse)
tibble(v1 = c(1234,1235,1236), v2= c('{"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61}','{"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24}','{"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10}')) %>% 
  mutate(v2 = gsub("\\{","",v2),
         v2 = gsub("\\}","",v2)) %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(v2,",") %>% 
  separate(v2, into = c("v2_1","v2_2"),sep = ":")
`

Comment: For this purpose yes, this is a data slice so that the information output from here can be uploaded into a GIS map for later spatial analysis. For that purpose, the data needs to be wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have JSON data in strings of `dat$V2`, so you can use a package like *jsonlite* to import them in a sensible format:

```
library(jsonlite)
si <- stream_in(textConnection(dat$v2), simplifyVector=FALSE)
dat[paste("v2", seq_along(si[[1]]), sep="_")] <- t(sapply(si, names))
dat[paste("v2", seq_along(si[[1]]), "num", sep="_")] <- do.call(Map, c(c, si))
dat

##    v1                                     v2         v2_1         v2_2 v2_1_num v2_2_num
##1 1234 {"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61} 484391115444 484391115442      192       61
##2 1235  {"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24} 484391115432 484391115443       52       24
##3 1236  {"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10} 484391115302 484391115161       11       10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate_wider()` to do what you would like to do.
Separate the first 10 columns, drop anything that goes beyond 10 and split them:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(
  v1 = c(1234, 1235, 1236),
  v2 = c(
    '{"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61}',
    '{"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24}',
    '{"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10}'
  )
) %>%
  mutate(
    v2 = gsub("\\{", "", v2),
    v2 = gsub("\\}", "", v2),
    v2 = gsub('"', "", v2)
  ) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(v2,
                       ",",
                       names = as.character(c(1:10)),
                       too_few = "align_start",
                       too_many = "drop") %>%
  separate_wider_delim(!v1, ":", names_sep = "_")
```

Producing this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 13
     v1 `1_1`        `1_2` `2_1`        `2_2` `3_1` `4_1` `5_1` `6_1` `7_1` `8_1` `9_1` `10_1`
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1  1234 484391115444 192   484391115442 61    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
2  1235 484391115432 52    484391115443 24    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    
3  1236 484391115302 11    484391115161 10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A `separate_rows` approach should work with any number of columns. First we convert to a longer format with a new row for every entry in `v2` separated by `,`. Then we split those into two pieces separated by `:` and extract the numeric part (an alternative to your gsub approach). Finally, we pivot wider, where any missing entries will be NA, but the table will be as wide as it needs to be to accommodate the longest nested entry.

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(v1 = c(1234,1235,1236), 
       v2= c('{"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61}',
             '{"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24}',
             '{"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10}')) |>
  separate_rows(v2, sep = ",") |>
  mutate(entry = row_number(), .by = v1) |>
  separate(v2, c("id1", "id2"), sep = ":") |>
  mutate(across(id1:id2, readr::parse_number)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = entry, values_from = c(id1, id2), names_vary = "slowest")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     v1        id1_1 id2_1        id1_2 id2_2
  <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
1  1234 484391115444   192 484391115442    61
2  1235 484391115432    52 484391115443    24
3  1236 484391115302    11 484391115161    10
```

Comment: thank you. will separate_rows work on a column that is type character? Would I need to convert the character type to something else before hand?

Comment: `v2` is character in this example and it works for me. Please say more if it's not working for you.

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error in UseMethod("separate_rows") : 
no applicable method for 'separate_rows' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: It sounds like you are feeding a character vector into it and not a data frame that contains a character vector as one of its variables? Compare `letters |> separate_rows()` [I get your error] vs.  `data.frame(letters = letters) |> separate_rows()`.

Comment: Yes? I think I lost something in understanding your answer in setting the tibble. This is my lack of R knowledge surfacing.

Comment: `separate_rows`, like many tidyverse functions, expects to receive a data frame or tibble as its first argument, which simplifies chaining with `|>` or `%>%`. Can you share the output of `dput(head(my_df))` in the body of your question so we can confirm our solutions will work with the data the way you have it? The answers so far have all assumed you have a tibble with a character column called `v2` but maybe you don't?

Comment: Correct, I used short variable names in the question. With 25k rows, do I need to put in all values of v1 in C()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256087/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-roninuta).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would want to have a lot of control over it and would prefer two `str_split`s.  Then, can work with either the nested data frame that results, a wide, or a long unnested one.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  v1 = 1234:1236, 
  v2 = c('{"484391115444":192,"484391115442":61}', 
         '{"484391115432":52,"484391115443":24}',
         '{"484391115302":11,"484391115161":10}')
)

prs <- function(v) {
  v |> 
    str_remove_all('\\{|\\}|\\"') |> 
    str_split(",") |> 
    map(str_split, ":", simplify = TRUE) |> 
    map(as_tibble, .name_repair = "unique_quiet") |> 
    map(set_names, c("name", "value"))
}

# nested
df |> 
  mutate(v2 = prs(v2))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      v1 v2              
#>   <int> <list>          
#> 1  1234 <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 2  1235 <tibble [2 × 2]>
#> 3  1236 <tibble [2 × 2]>

# long
df |> 
  mutate(v2 = prs(v2)) |> 
  unnest(v2)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>      v1 name         value
#>   <int> <chr>        <chr>
#> 1  1234 484391115444 192  
#> 2  1234 484391115442 61   
#> 3  1235 484391115432 52   
#> 4  1235 484391115443 24   
#> 5  1236 484391115302 11   
#> 6  1236 484391115161 10

# wide
df |> 
  mutate(v2 = prs(v2)) |> 
  unnest(v2) |> 
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>      v1 `484391115444` `484391115442` `484391115432` `484391115443`
#>   <int> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
#> 1  1234 192            61             <NA>           <NA>          
#> 2  1235 <NA>           <NA>           52             24            
#> 3  1236 <NA>           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>          
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: `484391115302` <chr>, `484391115161` <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>